# Що означає слово "злебенити”?

Tags: значення-слів, дієслова

У творі Панаса Мирного ["Хіба ревуть воли, як ясла повні"](http://lib.ru/SU/UKRAINA/MIRNIJ/h_r_v_ya.txt_Piece100.01) натрапила на таке речення:

> Недовго й мiсця шукав:  зараз  жид  **злебенив**  його  та  й заправив у поштарi.

Отож цікавить, що означає слово "***злебенити***".

Шукала у [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/zlebenyty),однак там цього слова немає.

Comment: Пишу не про конкретно це ваше запитання, а загалом. Будь ласка, приймайте (✓) відповіді на запитання _трохи повільніше_ (часто бачив, як ви приймаєте першу ж відповідь десь протягом години після її появи). Маю припущення, що коли користувачі бачать «вже розв'язане» питання, вони частково втрачають ентузіазм до написання власної відповіді, а було б добре мати по декілька відповідей (декілька кутів зору) на кожне запитання (це заохочується політикою цього сайту, і наша спільнота таку політику підтримує).

Comment: Тобто приймайте, будь ласка, відповідь лише тоді, коли вважаєте, що вона _справді неперевершена_, а в решті випадків давайте пару діб на написання іншими користувачами інших відповідей. Дякую. В цьому питанні також пропоную розглянути обидві відповіді вже тепер і вирішити, яку приймати.

Comment: Дякую за зауваги та поради!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пропоную інший варіант відповіді для тих, хто не знає російської й надає перевагу літературній мові для розуміння незрозумілих слів.

[Українсько-англійський словник 1955р.](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%CC%81%D1%82%D0%B8&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) (К. Андрусишин, Я. Крет):

> **злебені́ти** (-і́ю, -і́єш) Р vt = *злебеда́ти*.
>
> *злебеда́ти* (-а́ю, -а́єш) P vt to catch (seize) unexpectedly, surprise.

Отже, *злебеніти* - це **несподівано схопити**, **заскочити**.

Answer (score 1):

У [Словнику за ред. Б. Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/20256-zlebenity.html) знаходимо:

> **Злебені́ти**, -ню́, -ниш, гл. Попасть, схватить. Зараз жид злебенив його та й заправив у поштарі. Мир. ХРВ. 4.

Отже,  «зараз жид **схопив** його та й заправив у поштарі».